# how to fix problem with initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to create a kernel module, which creates a  subdirectory in the /proc directory, and contains a file that can be written and read from user space.

But always when I compile the module I get the same errors:

```
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
.read = read_proc,
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
.write = write_proc,
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
     Our_Proc_File->read_proc = read_proc;
```

Code:

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define MODULE
#include<linux/seq_file.h> 
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>   
#include <asm/uaccess.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("1");


#define MAXBUFFSIZE 256
static char mm_buff[MAXBUFFSIZE];


static struct proc_dir_entry* Our_Proc_File;
static struct proc_dir_entry* Our_Proc_Dir;

static ssize_t read_proc(  char* buffer,  char** buffer_location, off_t offset,
        int buffer_length,  int* eof, void* data)
{
        int len =0;
        static int count = 1;

        if(offset > 0){
                *eof = 1;
                return len;
        }

        len = sprintf(buffer,"[%d] %s\n",count++,mm_buff);
        return len;
}

static ssize_t write_proc( struct file* file,const char* buffer, unsigned long count,
            void *data){

        if(count < (MAXBUFFSIZE-1)){
                strncpy(mm_buff,buffer,count);
                mm_buff[count] = '\0';
                printk("Buffer: %s\n",mm_buff);
        }
        return count;
}


static struct file_operations myops =
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = read_proc,
    .write = write_proc,
};

static int __init simple_init(void)
{


        printk("MyModule Loaded Successfully\n");

        Our_Proc_Dir = proc_mkdir("Colours",NULL);
        if(IS_ERR(Our_Proc_Dir)){
                printk("Failed to create directory\n");
                return -1;
        }

        Our_Proc_File = proc_create("Orange",0644,Our_Proc_Dir,&myops);
       if(IS_ERR(Our_Proc_File)){
                proc_remove(Our_Proc_Dir);
                return -1;
        }

        Our_Proc_File->read_proc = read_proc;
        Our_Proc_File->write_proc =write_proc;

        return 0;
}

static void __exit fun(void){
        if(Our_Proc_File)
 proc_remove(Our_Proc_File);
 if(Our_Proc_Dir)
 proc_remove(Our_Proc_Dir);
        printk("MyModule Exit!\n");

}

module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(fun);
```

Comment: `Our_Proc_File->read_proc = read_proc;` doesn't work because you have no definition of `struct proc_dir_entry` in scope, and even if you did, it doesn't have any member called `read_proc`.  But I don't think you are supposed to be messing around with its members in the first place - AFAIK it's meant to be an opaque type.  Why are these lines here?

Comment: Are you writing this based on some documentation or tutorial?  If so, could you give a link or reference?  It may be that it contains errors, or that you're misreading it in some way.

Comment: read_proc_t and write_proc_t need to return int. ssize_t may translate to something else. I'm referring to this link
https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/proc__fs_8h.html#aaae14756cd593c8067329476cf379114

Comment: http://tarekamr.appspot.com/blog/unix-proc-filesystem.html

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
> .read = read_proc,
> error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
> .write = write_proc,
> ```

The signature expected of the read function is

```
ssize_t R (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

The signature expected of the write function is

```
ssize_t W (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

(https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html)

The the names of the functions and of their parameters do not matter, but the return type and the number, order, and types of the arguments all do.

Your `read_proc()` doesn't appear to match at all.  I guess its possible that it's closer to right for some other version of the kernel than the doc I linked describes.  Your `write_proc()` function is closer, but `unsigned long` is probably not the same type as `size_t`, and `void *` is probably not the same type as `loff_t *`. Either one of those discrepancies is enough for a pointer type mismatch, and they could cause genuine behavioral issues.

> ```
> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
>      Our_Proc_File->read_proc = read_proc;
> ```

It is not necessary to have the definition of `struct proc_dir_entry` to declare a pointer to that type, but it *is* necessary to have a definition in order to access members of an instance, via such a pointer or otherwise.  At the point where you attempt to do

```
    Our_Proc_File->read_proc = read_proc;
```

, no such definition is in scope.  Possibly you have forgotten to include the appropriate header.  Alternatively, you may have misspelled the structure tag.